# Missing plugin Amplifydatastore in Flutter using web

Tags: amazon-web-services, flutter

https://docs.amplify.aws/start/getting-started/integrate/q/integration/flutter/#querying-for-todos-and-observing-updates-in-real-time

So I am following this tutorial up to **Updating a Todo** to use Flutter with AWS. Where I get the following. I am also getting a platform error with Windows.

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Unsupported operation: This platform is not supported yet
    at Object.throw_ [as throw] (errors.dart:251:49)
    at AmplifyClass.new (amplify_impl.dart:40:7)
    at get instance (amplify_impl.dart:133:34)
    at desc.get [as instance] (operations.dart:839:8)
    at get Amplify [as Amplify] (amplify_flutter.dart:26:42)
    at main._TodosPageState.new._initializeApp (main.dart:78:10)
    at _initializeApp.next (<anonymous>)
    at async_patch.dart:45:50
    at _RootZone.runUnary (zone.dart:1685:54)
    at _FutureListener.thenAwait.handleValue (future_impl.dart:147:18)
    at handleValueCallback (future_impl.dart:766:44)
    at _Future._propagateToListeners (future_impl.dart:795:13)
    at [_completeWithValue] (future_impl.dart:566:5)
    at async._AsyncCallbackEntry.new.callback (future_impl.dart:639:7)
    at Object._microtaskLoop (schedule_microtask.dart:40:11)
    at _startMicrotaskLoop (schedule_microtask.dart:49:5)
    at async_patch.dart:166:15
```

I'm assuming it's something to do with **_dataStorePlugin**

Traceback:

```
PS C:\users\arund\desktop\aws-projects\amplified_todo> flutter run
Multiple devices found:
Chrome (web) • chrome • web-javascript • Google Chrome 102.0.5005.115
Edge (web)   • edge   • web-javascript • Microsoft Edge 103.0.1264.37
[1]: Chrome (chrome)
[2]: Edge (edge)
Please choose one (To quit, press "q/Q"): 1
Launching lib\main.dart on Chrome in debug mode...
Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome...             51.6s
This app is linked to the debug service: ws://127.0.0.1:49346/mk_K-qpY2-s=/ws
Debug service listening on ws://127.0.0.1:49346/mk_K-qpY2-s=/ws

 Running with sound null safety 

  To hot restart changes while running, press "r" or "R".
For a more detailed help message, press "h". To quit, press "q".

An Observatory debugger and profiler on Chrome is available at: http://127.0.0.1:49346/mk_K-qpY2-s=
Flutter Web Bootstrap: Auto
══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY SERVICES LIBRARY ╞══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following MissingPluginException was thrown while activating platform stream on channel
com.amazonaws.amplify/datastore_hub_events:
MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method listen on channel
com.amazonaws.amplify/datastore_hub_events)

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/errors.dart
251:49  throw_
packages/flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart 165:7
_invokeMethod
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 45:50
<fn>
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/zone.dart 1685:54
runUnary
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 147:18
handleValue
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 766:44
handleValueCallback
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 795:13
_propagateToListeners
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 566:5
[_completeWithValue]
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 639:7
callback
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/schedule_microtask.dart 40:11
_microtaskLoop
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/schedule_microtask.dart 49:5
_startMicrotaskLoop
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 166:15
<fn>
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
Amplify plugin was not added
An error occurred while configuring Amplify: AmplifyException(message: Amplify plugin AmplifyDataStore was not added
successfully., recoverySuggestion: We currently don't have a recovery suggestion for this exception.,
underlyingException: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method configureDataStore on channel
com.amazonaws.amplify/datastore))
Error: AmplifyException(message: DataStore plugin has not been added to Amplify, recoverySuggestion: Add DataStore
plugin to Amplify and call configure before calling DataStore related APIs, underlyingException: null)
    at Object.throw_ [as throw] (http://localhost:49308/dart_sdk.js:5080:11)
    at DataStoreCategory.observeQuery
    (http://localhost:49308/packages/amplify_flutter/src/categories/amplify_categories.dart.lib.js:612:236)
    at main._TodosPageState.new._initializeApp (http://localhost:49308/packages/amplified_todo/main.dart.lib.js:983:65)
    at http://localhost:49308/dart_sdk.js:40641:33
    at _RootZone.runUnary (http://localhost:49308/dart_sdk.js:40511:59)
    at handleValueCallback (http://localhost:49308/dart_sdk.js:35999:49)
    at _Future._propagateToListeners (http://localhost:49308/dart_sdk.js:36037:17)
    at [_completeError] (http://localhost:49308/dart_sdk.js:35878:23)
    at handleError (http://localhost:49308/dart_sdk.js:35058:38)
    at _RootZone.runBinary (http://localhost:49308/dart_sdk.js:40515:59)
    at _FutureListener.then.handleError (http://localhost:49308/dart_sdk.js:35449:33)
    at handleError (http://localhost:49308/dart_sdk.js:36015:51)
    at _Future._propagateToListeners (http://localhost:49308/dart_sdk.js:36041:17)
    at [_completeWithValue] (http://localhost:49308/dart_sdk.js:35872:23)
    at async._AsyncCallbackEntry.new.callback (http://localhost:49308/dart_sdk.js:35906:35)
    at Object._microtaskLoop (http://localhost:49308/dart_sdk.js:40778:13)
    at _startMicrotaskLoop (http://localhost:49308/dart_sdk.js:40784:13)
    at http://localhost:49308/dart_sdk.js:36261:9
The Flutter DevTools debugger and profiler on Chrome is available at:
http://127.0.0.1:9102?uri=http://127.0.0.1:49346/mk_K-qpY2-s=
An error occurred while saving Todo: AmplifyException(message: DataStore plugin has not been added to Amplify,
recoverySuggestion: Add DataStore plugin to Amplify and call configure before calling DataStore related APIs,
underlyingException: null)
```

My code is the same as the tutorial.

main

```
// dart async library we will refer to when setting up real time updates
import 'dart:async';

// flutter and ui libraries
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

// amplify packages we will need to use
import 'package:amplify_flutter/amplify_flutter.dart';
import 'package:amplify_datastore/amplify_datastore.dart';

// amplify configuration and models that should have been generated for you
import 'amplifyconfiguration.dart';
import 'models/ModelProvider.dart';
import 'models/Todo.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      title: 'Amplified Todo',
      home: TodosPage(),
    );
  }
}

class TodosPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const TodosPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<TodosPage> createState() => _TodosPageState();
}

class _TodosPageState extends State<TodosPage> {
  // subscription of Todo QuerySnapshots - to be initialized at runtime
  late StreamSubscription<QuerySnapshot<Todo>> _subscription;
  // loading ui state - initially set to a loading state
  bool _isLoading = true;

  // list of Todos - initially empty
  List<Todo> _todos = [];

  // amplify plugins
  final _dataStorePlugin = AmplifyDataStore(modelProvider: ModelProvider.instance);
  @override
  void initState() {
    // to be filled in a later step
    // kick off app initialization
    _initializeApp();

    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    // to be filled in a later step
    super.dispose();
  }

  Future<void> _initializeApp() async {
    // to be filled in a later step
    // configure Amplify
    await _configureAmplify();

    // Query and Observe updates to Todo models. DataStore.observeQuery() will
    // emit an initial QuerySnapshot with a list of Todo models in the local store,
    // and will emit subsequent snapshots as updates are made
    //
    // each time a snapshot is received, the following will happen:
    // _isLoading is set to false if it is not already false
    // _todos is set to the value in the latest snapshot
    _subscription = Amplify.DataStore.observeQuery(Todo.classType)
        .listen((QuerySnapshot<Todo> snapshot) {
      setState(() {
        if (_isLoading) _isLoading = false;
        _todos = snapshot.items;
      });
    });
 
  }

  Future<void> _configureAmplify() async {
    // to be filled in a later step
    try {

      // add Amplify plugins
      await Amplify.addPlugins([_dataStorePlugin]);

      // configure Amplify
      //
      // note that Amplify cannot be configured more than once!
      await Amplify.configure(amplifyconfig);
    } catch (e) {

      // error handling can be improved for sure!
      // but this will be sufficient for the purposes of this tutorial
      print('An error occurred while configuring Amplify: $e');
    }
  
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('My Todo List'),
      ),
      //body: const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
      body: _isLoading
           ? Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator())
           : TodosList(todos: _todos),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton.extended(
        onPressed: () {
          Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const AddTodoForm()),
          );
        },
        tooltip: 'Add Todo',
        label: Row(
          children: const [Icon(Icons.add), Text('Add todo')],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerFloat,
    );
  }
}

class TodosList extends StatelessWidget {
  const TodosList({
    required this.todos,
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final List<Todo> todos;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return todos.isNotEmpty
        ? ListView(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
            children: todos.map((todo) => TodoItem(todo: todo)).toList())
        : const Center(
            child: Text('Tap button below to add a todo!'),
          );
  }
}

class TodoItem extends StatelessWidget {
  const TodoItem({
    required this.todo,
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final double iconSize = 24.0;
  final Todo todo;

  void _deleteTodo(BuildContext context) async {
    // to be filled in a later step
  }

  Future<void> _toggleIsComplete() async {
    // to be filled in a later step
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Card(
      child: InkWell(
        onTap: () {
          _toggleIsComplete();
        },
        onLongPress: () {
          _deleteTodo(context);
        },
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: Row(children: [
            Expanded(
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  Text(
                    todo.name,
                    style: const TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                  ),
                  Text(todo.description ?? 'No description'),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Icon(
                todo.isComplete
                    ? Icons.check_box
                    : Icons.check_box_outline_blank,
                size: iconSize),
          ]),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class AddTodoForm extends StatefulWidget {
  const AddTodoForm({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<AddTodoForm> createState() => _AddTodoFormState();
}

class _AddTodoFormState extends State<AddTodoForm> {
  final _nameController = TextEditingController();
  final _descriptionController = TextEditingController();

  Future<void> _saveTodo() async {
    // to be filled in a later step
    // get the current text field contents
    final name = _nameController.text;
    final description = _descriptionController.text;

    // create a new Todo from the form values
    // `isComplete` is also required, but should start false in a new Todo
    final newTodo = Todo(
        name: name,
        description: description.isNotEmpty ? description : null,
        isComplete: false,
    );

    try {
      // to write data to DataStore, we simply pass an instance of a model to
      // Amplify.DataStore.save()
      await Amplify.DataStore.save(newTodo);

      // after creating a new Todo, close the form
      Navigator.of(context).pop();
    } catch (e) {
      print('An error occurred while saving Todo: $e');
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Add Todo'),
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
            children: [
              TextFormField(
                controller: _nameController,
                decoration:
                    const InputDecoration(filled: true, labelText: 'Name'),
              ),
              TextFormField(
                controller: _descriptionController,
                decoration: const InputDecoration(
                    filled: true, labelText: 'Description'),
              ),
              ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: _saveTodo,
                child: const Text('Save'),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm running into the exact same issue when running the Amplify Flutter Todo  app on web. It looks like Amplify Flutter still doesn't support web at this stage: https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-flutter/issues/443

Comment: still same issue with amplify flutter todo on web :(, so what is that developer preview thing?